# 2016 ford explorer signature LED headlight issues

Tags: ford, headlight, explorer, led

My passenger headlight is out and the drivers stays on for good 10 min after the truck is turned off and it will blink several times. Also while driving the drivers light will change from daytime running brightness to full nighttime brightness

Comment: Welcome to the site. What exactly is your question here? What have you investigated to try and fix your issue?

Comment: Wanted too find out if anyone has had similar problem or worked on explorer with this problem you can't just buy replacement led lamp from Ford you have to get entire  headlight assembly for 800.00  I figured it is electrical issue since one light is out and the other isn't working properly

Comment: I'm not sure how the Explorer's headlights are done, but you could try and see if the passenger side bulb will work on the driver's side ... at least illuminate. This will tell you if it's good or bad. You can also check stuff as Solar Mike mentions in his answer just to see if there are any issues there.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I don't see any reference to the headlamps staying on any longer than 3 minutes in SI. Any error codes pulled from modules would be nice. In this particular Ford, like most others, the BCM detects a headlight request, sends power through an FET and communicates with the headlamp module to control lighting. If one isn't working it's either a BCM, wiring or headlamp assembly problem. There aren't separate fuses for each headlight like in older models.

Answer (score 0):

Check the supply and fuses and bulb unit to get the passenger side working : this is for safety and therefore higher priority than the other questions you ask.

Answer (score 0):

Explore has 2separate fusses 1 for the right side  and 1for left head light 
Left light  sounds like it might be trying to tell you that the right light is out    or it has something to do with the alarm system

Answer (score 0):

If it's a 2016 model year, it should still be under factory warrantee.  If so, have a Ford dealer fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The ballasts are typically the issue....poor design at the very bottom of the headlight housing makes them very sensitive to moisture.   Fuses will not fix the issue. Here are typical errors codes for such problems [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDaEl.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to stack, because pictures eventually go bad or go away and are not searchable, can you add the text of the message to your answer?